# Cubic refuses to install or uninstall programs

Tags: custom-distributions

I'm currently trying to add and remove packages from the ubuntu 22.04 ISO, and upon trying to remove firefox, I get this:

```
root@cubic:~# apt remove firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'firefox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

after this, I tried installing neofetch as a test, which resulted in this:

```
root@cubic:~# apt install neofetch -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package neofetch
```

I am using the standard ubuntu 22.04 desktop ISO from canonicals site, and I have very little experience with cubic. I have watched tutorials on cubic for older versions of linux,  but after trying the same process with their version the problems are unchanged. Any ideas would be great
Thanks!

Comment: `firefox` in 22.04 is provided by a snap, not a deb, so apt cannot see it. `neofetch` is in the universe packet of the Ubuntu repositories; ensure that you have universe enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the second part of your question first.

You are unable to install packages because you have not added the appropriate repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

The `neofetch` package is in the `universe` repository.

It's a good idea to make sure you have all the important repsotories; to do that, use the following commands:

```
add-apt-repository --yes main
add-apt-repository --yes restricted
add-apt-repository --yes universe
add-apt-repository --yes multiverse
```

Then execute `apt install neofetch` and it will work.

Regarding the first part of your question, @user535733 is correct: Firefox is a snap in Ubuntu 22.04, so you can not use `apt` to manage it.

Unfortunately, you can not use snap commands in [Cubic's terminal environment](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Page) because services such as `snapd` do not run.

However, you could remove snap (and consequently remove all snap packages), then simply install the `deb` versions of those packages.

To remove `snap`, execute:

```
apt purge snapd
```

To install the `deb` version of Firefox, follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/100356).